# Issue related to Counting Record on Group by clause

Tags: sql-server

I have one database table having  `StudentId(int),Subject(varchar(50)),Marks(int),IsPass(int),ExamDate(Datetime)`

Table can have more than one record for same Subject for particular student for different Date.

I wrote following query :

```
select StudentId, Count(IsPass) 
from ExamEntry
where IsPass =1  group by StudentId
```

but dont want Where condition in the Query:

it is Possible something like this :

```
Select StudentId, case when IsPass = 1 then count(IsPass) end 
from ExamEntry 
group by studentId
```

but it display more that one record for perticular studentId

How can i achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use where clause for it than Having clause is its simplest alternate.

Try this out.

```
select StudentId, count(IsPass)AS PassedCount
from ExamEntry
group by StudentId,IsPass
having IsPass= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is so simple nobody saw it  :-)

```
SELECT StudentId, SUM(IsPass) 
FROM ExamEntry GROUP BY StudentId
```

Comment: @Remou: good idea. I did not put it due to the name of the field (IsPass) and the fact the question mentions "=1". I guessed it was 0 or 1. This seems linked to a c# app. I don't know what would be stored in there if bound to a combo in c#: 1 or -1 for True ?

Comment: I am not paying sufficient attention :(

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT StudentId,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN IsPass = 1 THEN 'X' END) AS NumberOfPasses
FROM   ExamEntry
GROUP  BY StudentId
```

`COUNT` only counts `NOT NULL` values and `CASE` has an implicit `ELSE NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You need something like this?

```
SELECT StudentId, SUM(CASE WHEN IsPass = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Number_Of_Passed_Exams
FROM ExamEntry
GROUP BY StudentId
```